# Is it possible to execute multiple _addItem calls asynchronously using Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Would the following code work?

```
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '7171717117', // order ID - required
    '',           // affiliation or store name
    '2222',       // total - required
    '',           // tax
    '',           // shipping
    '',           // city
    '',           // state or province
    ''            // country
]);
_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);

_gaq.push(['_addItem',
    '7171717117',   // order ID - required
    '22j33j2kjk',   // SKU/code - required
    'Widget 1.0',   // product name
    '',             // category or variation
    '2222',         // unit price - required
    '1'             // quantity - required
]);
_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);
```

Comment: You can always push more items to a collection. However, you need to get them in there before the information gets sent back to Google or else it will do you no good.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear. I want to send the transaction, then add items later.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> _trackTrans() Sends both the transaction and item data to the Google Analytics server. This method should be called after _trackPageview(),
>   and used in conjunction with the _addItem() and addTrans() methods. It
>   should be called after items and transaction elements have been set
>   up.

So, according to the docs, the items get sent when you call trackTrans(). Until you do, you can add items, but the transaction will not be sent.

Edit: Further reading led me here:

http://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/edit-ecommerce-data

Where it clearly says you can start another transaction with an existing ID. When you commit it, the new items you listed will be added to that transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Eran, but it still does not explicitly address the question I have. Each _addItem has an orderId that corresponds to the same orderId passed with the transaction. There should be no reason that Google can not associate the items with the transactions on the server. The reason I'm asking this questions is because I can't send the transaction and the items in the same call (for performance reasons). Therefore, I need an answer that explicitly states whether this is (or is not) possible.

Comment: I think the specs are quite clear on that. They state that you commit a transaction when you're done adding items to it. I agree that in theory they should be able to associate an item with a committed transaction, but nowhere in the docs is that option mentioned. The fastest way, other than to get a Google developer to reply, would be to run a simple test. Commit a transaction with one item, then add another item, and try to re-commit the transaction (that's where the catch would lie, I believe - commiting a transaction with an existing ID).

Comment: Edit: possibly good news. See here:

http://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/edit-ecommerce-data